# Slow development workflow/feedback loop for Java with Docker: do I need to rebuild the JAR and image after every change?

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to dockerize a Java app, but currently my development feedback loop is much slower when working **with** Docker compared to when I am working **without** Docker.  **With** Docker, I have to rebuild my jar and the image after every change (see more detailed workflow below), causing a slow feedback loop. What do Java devs in the Docker world do to avoid this?

Dockerfile (for reference):

```
FROM openjdk:8    
WORKDIR /usr/src/app  
COPY /target/my-project.jar .  
CMD ["java",  "-jar",  "my-project.jar"]
```

Java development workflow **with** Docker (feedback takes 3-5 minutes after each change):

1. Make a change locally to my Java codebase.
2. However small the change in #1 is, I need to rebuild my jar (using maven package); this takes 3-4 minutes for my codebase.
3. Rebuild image.
4. Run container and see if change went through.

Java development workflow **without** Docker (feedback takes seconds after each change):

1. Make a change locally to my Java codebase.
2. Click run on my Intellij run configuration, which runs my main method immediately, and see if changes went through.

From what I can tell, my local development feedback loop (without Docker) is so much faster because Intellij is able to cache all bytecode (i.e., the class files in the "target/" directory), rebuilds the class file(s) for only the class(es) that changed, keeps track of my classpath, and runs my main method. It doesn't need to rebuild the entire jar, and therefore is much, much faster. I'm not sure how to replicate this in Docker.

**UPDATE/ANSWER**

I solved this problem with the following approach:

1. Bind-mounted my project's target folder to /usr/src/app/target in the container and now just call the main class in my Dockerfile CMD, not ever bringing the JAR into the container. Thanks to @kutschkem.
2. Added maven-dependency-plugin to my pom.xml, so that all of my external jar dependencies could be saved to one folder (/usr/src/app/target/dependency-jars/), which I could then add to my classpath in one fell swoop in my Dockerfile CMD below. Got the idea from this article: https://medium.com/holisticon-consultants/dont-build-fat-jars-for-docker-applications-6252a5571248.

New Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8    
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/target
CMD ["java",  "-cp", "/usr/src/app/target/classes:/usr/src/app/target/dependency-jars/*",  "com.me.MainClass"]
```

Comment: Why must you do active development in Docker?  It should work to generally use your "without Docker" path, and when your code generally works (passes its unit tests, you can demo it in a desktop setup) only then look at Docker for integration tests and deployment.

Comment: @DavidMaze my reason for trying to set up for active development in docker is basically chasing what I thought was one of the main benefits of Docker: allowing for someone to help me out on the project without needing to download Java on their local machine. maybe that's not realistic/the best approach though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that can be improved here:

1) Don't copy the jar file to the image, mount the folder in the container as a volume with `-v`

2) If building the jar is an issue, then don't! Prepare a java invocation that includes the necessary classpath, and calls the main class. No need for a jar.

Of course this is for development, but functionally there shouldn't be much difference. Also, is there a good reason to test the classes inside the docker container? If I were to do it, I would seperate the development of the Java classes and the Docker image, and use the workflow you described WITHOUT docker to test my Java code, and only once I am satisfied turn to the image development.

Comment: I had thought about #2, but wasn't sure how I would go about dynamically keeping track of the classpath if it were to change. Regarding the reason for why I was trying to test my classes inside the docker container, you can see my response to David Maze above. I am definitely open to ditching that approach and going the WITHOUT Docker way for local development if that's the smartest/most practical way. Thanks for your help!